# Unit testing a directive that uses clientHeight

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that watches the clientHeight of an element with dynamic height and sets a scope variable to that value, but I can't figure out how to unit test it at all. Everything I've done in the unit tests, clientHeight always returns 0. I've tried a number of different solutions I've read for similar problems on here, but none of them work.

Here is the directive:

```
return {
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(function () { return element[0].clientHeight; },
      function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
          scope.$parent.headerHeight = newValue;
        }
      }, true);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of detached DOM element are 0. The element should be appended to DOM before its dimensions are measured and torn down at the end of the test:

```
element = $compile('<directive>')(scope);
angular.element(document.body).append(element);
scope.$digest();
...
element.remove();
```

To efficiently test it apart from DOM (which is the domain of e2e tests, not unit tests) anonymous watch function should be exposed to scope

```
scope._getHeight = function () { return element[0].clientHeight; };
scope.$watch('_getHeight()', ...);
```

and mocked, because it is directive logic that is tested, not browser rendering engine:

```
element = $compile('<directive>')(scope);
spyOn(scope, '_getHeight').and.returnValue(100);
scope.$digest();
...
```